# GWT TreeViewModel not working as expected

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to make a CellTree in GWT, but for some reason the TreeViewModel is no working properly

```
public class ChannelViewModel implements TreeViewModel {

  @Override
  public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(T value) {

    if(value == null)
    {
        Window.alert("NODE 0");
        return new DefaultNodeInfo<ChannelRepresentation>(new ChannelAsyncDataProvider(), new ChannelCell() );

    } else if(value instanceof ChannelRepresentation)
    {
        Window.alert("NODE 1");
        ChannelRepresentation feedChannel = (ChannelRepresentation) value ;
        return new DefaultNodeInfo<EntryRepresentation>( new EntryAsyncDataProvider( feedChannel.getChannelURI() ), new FeedEntryCell() );
    }
    Window.alert("Undefined Value");
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isLeaf(Object value) {
    if(value instanceof EntryRepresentation)
    {
        Window.alert("isLeaf: True");
        return true;
    }
    Window.alert("isLeaf: False");
    return false;
  }
}
```

What makes me think the problem is in the TreeViewModel class is that if i make the method isLeaf() always return false it starts rendering the nodes for entry representation.

Besides, i tested the data providers separately and they work ok, to me the problem seems to be in the TreeViewModel. If i use any of the examples of the GWT it works perfectly and i think i've tried everything to figure this out, so any help would be highly appreciated

EDIT:
This is my onModuleLoad() method if it serves something

```
    public void onModuleLoad() {

    ChannelViewModel model = new ChannelViewModel();
    CellTree tree = new CellTree(model, null);

    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(tree);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to this statement:

```
CellTree tree = new CellTree(model, null);
```

The second parameter should not be null!